# Trouble with Whois Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
if (command === 'whois') {
    let user;
    if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
        user = message.mentions.users.first();
    } else {
        user = message.author;
    }
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
            
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setThumbnail(`${member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
        .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
        .addField("ID:", `${user.id}`, true)
        .addField("Nickname:", `${member.nickname !== null ? `${member.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
        .addField("Status:", user.presence.status, true)
        .addField("Playing", `${member.user.presence.activities}  `)
        .addField("Joined Discord At", member.user.createdAt)
        .addField("Roles", member.roles.cache.map(r => '`'+r.name+'`').join(' - '), true)
        .setFooter(`${client.user.username}`)

    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

I keep getting the error
(node:19788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
im not sure what to do.

Comment: I've never used this API, but after a bit of investigation I see that `message.channel.send(embed)` fails by throwing an error which is not caught. This is why you see error "UnhandlerPromiseRejectionWarning". Try to catch the error similarly to this example: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send, and the investigate further. It looks like the problem is specific to Discord API and/or the library itself. It is almost always a good idea to use `catch` when handling with promises (or try/catch if using async syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to change this line:

```
.addField("Playing", `${member.user.presence.activities}`)
```

into

```
.addField("Playing", `${member.user.presence.activities[0]}`)
```

because the activities are stored in an array but you just need the first values. If the user does nothing it is `undefined`. So you could do something like:

```js
.addField("Playing", `${member.user.presence.activities[0] !== undefined ? member.user.presence.activities[0].name} : "Nothing."`)
```

P.S: If you would like to see the activities, just do a `console.log(member.user.presence.activities[0])`.